# Uso da expressão "Tupi-Guarani"

Tags: etimologia

Por que classificam certas palavras como provenientes do Tupi-Guarani, sendo que são tribos distintas, inclusive na língua falada?

Exemplo tirado da história da cidade de Avaré ([Tudo sobre a cidade Avaré](http://www.encontraavare.com.br/avare/)):

"...
Avaré (ou Abaré) vem do tupi-guarani abaré-y, nome dado pelo intendente ("prefeito") da época Cel. Eduardo Lopes de Oliveira ao município, nome este que é de um morro arrendondado (morro Avaré) que existe ao sul do município de Itatinga e que fica na então sua propriedade Fazenda Avaré. Provavelmente Avaré queira apenas dizer "solitário", pois o tal morro está isolado de outros.
..."

Comment: Bem vindo Paulo! Interessante e bem-formulada sua questão, só peço que adiciones alguma referência ao trecho _sendo que são tribos distintas, inclusive na língua falada_, pois é uma afirmação não óbvia para aqueles que não conhecem tais idiomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa talvez seja mais uma questão de linguística que de português.

O [Tupi-Guarani](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADnguas_tupi-guaranis) é uma **subfamília linguística** com mais de 50 idiomas (incluindo o antigo Tupi e o Guarani), que pertence ao tronco linguístico [Macro-Tupi](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro-tupi), que engloba [cerca de 70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupian_languages) idiomas.